# Assistance with SQL script

Tags: sql, left-join, case, where-clause

I'm currently designing a `SQL` report, to be run from inside a **`ERP system`**. The idea behind this code, is to bring all **`AR`** open items, with all these fields in **`SELECT statement`**, and be able to chose which to run report for, by the various WHERE clauses options that I describe.

I enclose as well, the table inside **`ERP system`**, with "parameters" names, and the options user will have to run report as...

I'm not able to get all these CASE **`AND`**, **`OR`** statement to work, or provide specific data, based on search criteria.

I'm not even sure I'm showing the parameters correctly on the WHERE clause code (with the "**`< >`"**, or by field name, or with **`' '`**, ...)

[Sample Data](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=29626702457509858340)

[Report parameters](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=79492278758069143949)

```
SELECT DISTINCT
e1.rel_value AS Cust_Rep_Grp, 
o1.description AS Cust_Rep_Grp_Name, 
r.main_apar_id AS Head_Office, 
o2.description AS Head_Office_Name, 
s.apar_id AS CustID, 
o3.description AS Cust_ID_Name, 
s.voucher_no, 
s.dim_2 AS BookingNo, 
h.ext_ord_ref AS YourRef,  
n.booking_day_fx AS Booking_date, 
n.check_in_date_fx AS Check_in_date, 
n.check_out_date_fx AS Check_out_date, 
s.voucher_date AS Invoice_date,
s.due_date, 
i.art_descr AS Hotel_name, 
o.description AS Destination,
e2.rel_value AS City,
o.description AS City_name,
e.rel_value AS Country_code,
o4.description AS Country_name, 
n.guest_fx AS Client_name,
n.pax_fx, 
s.currency,
i.disc_percent AS Comm_percentage, 
s.cur_amount AS Net_amt, 
s.rest_curr AS Due_now,
s.voucher_type,
s.order_id 
FROM acutrans s
LEFT OUTER JOIN acuheader r
ON r.client = s.client
AND s.apar_id = r.apar_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN asoheader h
ON h.client = s.client
AND h.order_id = s.order_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN asodetail i
ON i.client = s.client
AND i.order_id = s.order_id
INNER JOIN algvirelvalue e2 
ON e2.client= s.client 
AND e2.rel_attr_id='ZZ06'
AND e2.related_attr = 'CITY' 
AND i.article = e2.article
LEFT OUTER JOIN aglrelvalue e 
ON e.client= s.client 
AND e.attribute_id = 'ZZ06'
AND e.rel_attr_id = 'C9'
AND e.att_value = e2.rel_value
LEFT OUTER JOIN aglrelvalue e1
ON e1.client = s.client
AND e1.attribute_id = 'A4'
AND e1.rel_attr_id = 'ZG06'
AND e1.att_value = s.apar_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN agldescription o 
ON o.client= s.client 
AND o.attribute_id='ZZ06' 
AND o.dim_value = e2.rel_value
LEFT OUTER JOIN agldescription o1 
ON o1.client= s.client 
AND o1.attribute_id='ZG06' 
AND o1.dim_value = e1.rel_value
LEFT OUTER JOIN agldescription o2 
ON o2.client= s.client 
AND o2.attribute_id='A4' 
AND o2.dim_value = r.main_apar_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN agldescription o3 
ON o3.client= s.client 
AND o3.attribute_id='A4' 
AND o3.dim_value = s.apar_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN agldescription o4 
ON o4.client= s.client 
AND o4.attribute_id='C9' 
AND o4.dim_value = e.rel_value
LEFT OUTER JOIN afxbooking_gen n 
ON s.dim_2 = n.dim_value 
AND s.client = n.client 
AND n.attribute_id = 'ZZ01'

WHERE  
      CASE WHEN '<checkin_from>' IN (' ','') THEN '*' ELSE '<checkin_from>' END LIKE n.check_in_date_fx
      AND  
      CASE WHEN n.check_in_date_fx IN (' ','') THEN '*' ELSE n.check_in_date_fx END LIKE n.check_in_date_fx
      OR
      CASE WHEN s.voucher_date IN (' ','') THEN '*' ELSE s.voucher_date END LIKE s.voucher_Date
      AND 
      CASE WHEN s.voucher_date IN (' ','') THEN '*' ELSE s.voucher_date END LIKE s.voucher_Date
      OR 
      CASE WHEN n.booking_day_fx IN (' ','') THEN '*' ELSE n.booking_day_fx END LIKE n.booking_day_fx
      AND
      CASE WHEN n.booking_day_fx IN (' ','') THEN '*' ELSE n.booking_day_fx END LIKE n.booking_day_fx
      OR 
      CASE WHEN n.check_out_date_fx IN (' ','') THEN '*' ELSE n.check_out_date_fx END LIKE n.check_out_date_fx
      AND 
      CASE WHEN n.check_out_date_fx IN (' ','') THEN '*' ELSE n.check_out_date_fx END LIKE n.check_out_date_fx  
      OR 
      CASE WHEN s.apar_id  IN (' ','') THEN '*' ELSE s.apar_id  END LIKE s.apar_id 
      AND
      CASE WHEN s.apar_id  IN (' ','') THEN '*' ELSE s.apar_id  END LIKE s.apar_id 
      OR 
      CASE WHEN o3.description IN (' ','') THEN '*' ELSE o3.description END LIKE o3.description
      OR 
      CASE WHEN e1.rel_value IN (' ','') THEN '*' ELSE e1.rel_value END LIKE e1.rel_value
      AND
      CASE WHEN e1.rel_value IN (' ','') THEN '*' ELSE e1.rel_value END LIKE e1.rel_value
      OR 
      CASE WHEN o1.description IN (' ','') THEN '*' ELSE o1.description END LIKE o1.description 
      OR 
      CASE WHEN r.main_apar_id IN (' ','') THEN '*' ELSE r.main_apar_id END LIKE r.main_apar_id
      AND
      CASE WHEN r.main_apar_idIN (' ','') THEN '*' ELSE r.main_apar_id END LIKE r.main_apar_id
      OR 
      CASE WHEN o2.description IN (' ','') THEN '*' ELSE o2.description END LIKE o2.description  
      OR 
      CASE WHEN s.dim_2 IN (' ','') THEN '*' ELSE s.dim_2 END LIKE s.dim_2
      AND
      CASE WHEN s.dim_2 IN (' ','') THEN '*' ELSE s.dim_2 END LIKE s.dim_2
      OR 
      CASE WHEN e.rel_value IN (' ','') THEN '*' ELSE e.rel_value END LIKE e.rel_value  
      OR 
      CASE WHEN s.currency  IN (' ','') THEN '*' ELSE s.currency  END LIKE s.currency  
      OR 
      CASE WHEN n.guest_fx IN (' ','') THEN '*' ELSE n.guest_fx END LIKE n.guest_fx 
      OR 
      CASE WHEN s.voucher_no IN (' ','') THEN '*' ELSE s.voucher_no END LIKE s.voucher_no
      AND
      CASE WHEN s.voucher_no IN (' ','') THEN '*' ELSE s.voucher_no END LIKE s.voucher_no
      OR 
      CASE WHEN h.ext_ord_ref IN (' ','') THEN '*' ELSE h.ext_ord_ref END LIKE h.ext_ord_ref
      OR 
      CASE WHEN s.order_id IN (' ','') THEN '*' ELSE s.order_id END LIKE s.order_id
      AND
      CASE WHEN s.order_id IN (' ','') THEN '*' ELSE s.order_id END LIKE s.order_id
```

Comment: What platform or language are you executing this query from? The where clause is not working because it is matching against itself (which is always true, you are not comparing the parameters at all

Comment: Are you trying to say that when the _parameter_ value is empty, you do not want to filter on that column?

Comment: @ChrisSchaller It's from Unit4 Business World, Report Engine. How can I write the parameters correctly, within the WHERE CLAUSE, that would allow user to chose 1 or various? Thank you

Comment: @ChrisSchaller When the parameter value is empty, bring it all from that parameter...but still filter on whatever parameter user has entered

Comment: You have combined date boundry filters and text filters. Are the date filters supposed to be exact matches or do you want the user to specify a date range, so to return all records where `checkin` date is between `checkin_from` and `checkin_to`?

Comment: Please include the sample data and expected output as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362), not some external links to dubious download sites. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking (text only) tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where to start?

Lets simplify this a bit.

1. Does the `SELECT` statement without the `WHERE` clause return the right structure. So if all the This is a large query to debug in a forum like this, so we need to target the response, for the rest of this solution we will assume that your `SELECT FROM` and `JOIN` syntax and linkages are correct.
2. Your `WHERE` criteria is not correct at all, it is not comparing to the input parameters at all.
   It appears that your filter criteria can be summed up as the union between some date and numeric range filters and some text and numeric exact match filters. Each of the filters is optional but the returned data must satisfy all parameters that are not empty.

   > I am not familiar with parameter syntax in *Unit4 Business World, Report Engine*, the following is a pure MS SQL example. Parameters will be prefixed with `@`, it is possible that *Unit4* has a custom parameter implementation, you will have to check the documentation.
   >
   > > As a general rule, when debugging `WHERE` criteria, it helps to comment out all except the first condition, then incrementally append the conditions, checking each time that the output is as expected, before adding the next condition.

I can identify the following conceptual filter criteria:

1. (checkin date) `n.check_in_date_fx` must be *greater than* or *equal to* `@checkin_from`
2. `n.check_in_date_fx` must be *less than* or *equal to* `@checkin_to`
3. `s.voucher_date` must be >= `@invdate_from`
4. `s.voucher_date` must be <= `@invdate_to`
5. `n.booking_day_fx` must be >= `@bookdate_fro`
6. `n.booking_day_fx` must be <= `@bookdate_to`
7. `n.check_out_date_fx` must be >= `@checkout_fro`
8. `n.check_out_date_fx` must be <= `@checkout_to`
9. (CustID) `s.apar_id` must be >= `@custid_from`
10. `s.apar_id` must be <= `@custid_to`
11. (CustomerName) `o3.description` `LIKE` `@custname`
    ...

> Lets stop there... We need to `AND` each of these criteria because they must all match, but then we can use brackets and add a sub `OR` criteria to each of these filters so they are in pairs of:
>
> WHERE
>           ( *parameter1* is *empty* **OR** filter criteria for *parameter1* matches ) 
>           **AND** ( *parameter2* is *empty* **OR** filter criteria for *parameter2* matches ) 
>           **AND** ( *parameter3* is *empty* **OR** filter criteria for *parameter3* matches )

So for those first filters we've identified, the `WHERE` clause looks like this:

> This Assumes that the *date* fields are actually stored as a `DATE` compatible data-type, the following will not work if they are stored as text...
>   *Also* assuming that the parameters are passed in as strings, if they are passed in as date type, then `IN (' ','')` will not work, you will instead have to use `null` date comparisons.

```
WHERE  
    ( @checkin_from IN (' ','') OR n.check_in_date_fx >= @checkin_from )
AND ( @checkin_to IN (' ','') OR n.check_in_date_fx <= @checkin_to )      
AND ( @invdate_from IN (' ','') OR s.voucher_date >= @invdate_from )
AND ( @invdate_to IN (' ','') OR s.voucher_date <= @invdate_to )
AND ( @bookdate_fro IN (' ','') OR n.booking_day_fx >= @bookdate_fro )
AND ( @bookdate_to IN (' ','') OR n.booking_day_fx <= @bookdate_to )
AND ( @checkout_fro IN (' ','') OR n.check_out_date_fx >= @checkout_fro )
AND ( @checkout_to IN (' ','') OR n.check_out_date_fx <= @checkout_to )
AND ( @custid_from IN (' ','') OR s.apar_id >= @custid_from )
AND ( @custid_to IN (' ','') OR s.apar_id <= @custid_to )
AND ( @custname IN (' ','') OR o3.description LIKE @custname )
...
```

You just keep appending the new criteria with `AND` making sure that inside the _and there is an the criteria to match on the empty parameter value `OR` the parameter matches the row.

If the date parameters are passed in as strings, and the DB fields are stored as *date* absed data types, then the above syntax should work. If the date parameters are actually passed in as proper `DATE` typed values, then string comparison may not work, an empty date might be passed in as `NULL`, if that is the case, then you may need to change the parameter logic to something like this:

```
AND ( @checkin_to IS NULL OR ... )
```

If the date fields are not stored as dates, then you will have to cast them to a date to allow date based comparisons, string based *greater than* or *less than* comparisons will only work if the dates are stored consistently in ISO format

I hope this discussion points you in the right direction.